# Apache TIKA: Tried to allocate an array of length 1835606, but 1000000 is the maximum for this record type

Tags: tika-server

Running Apache Ticka 1.24.1, as follows:

`java -Xmx3G -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mytmp/tmp -spawnChild -taskPulseMillis 240000 -jar tika-server.jar --host=hostname.domain.com`

Can the array length be changed to not get this error?

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException 
from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@4fab9c0a
...
...
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Tried to allocate 
an array of length 1835606, but 1000000 is the maximum for this record type.
If the file is not corrupt, please open an issue on bugzilla to request 
increasing the maximum allowable size for this record type.
As a temporary workaround, consider setting a higher override value with 
IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride()
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.throwRFE(IOUtils.java:630)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.checkLength(IOUtils.java:208)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.safelyAllocateCheck(IOUtils.java:610)
at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.safelyAllocate(IOUtils.java:596)
at org.apache.poi.hmef.attribute.MAPIRtfAttribute.<init 
(MAPIRtfAttribute.java:49)
...
org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OutlookExtractor.handleBodyChunks(
OutlookExtractor.java:328)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please add below configuration in your tika-config.xml  and let us know if it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <parsers>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
        <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser">
            <params>
                <param name="byteArrayMaxOverride" type="int">2000000</param>

            </params>
        </parser>
    </parsers>
</properties>
```